# Retrieve 4 different type of data in controller

Tags: html, laravel, view, controller, laravel-5.5

i want to retrieve 4 different type of product stocked in the same table and show it in one view 
each categorie with each product
[Look to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tEMa.png)

////******************The controller Code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Produit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');

        // carrelage
        $indexcarrelage = Produit::where('page',13)->get();
        return view('index',compact('indexcarrelage')); 
    //cuisine
        $indexcuisine = Produit::where('page',9)->get();
        return view('index',compact('indexcuisine'));
    //salle de bain
        $indexsalle = Produit::where('page',1)->get();
        return view('index',compact('indexsalle'));
    //meuble
        $indexmeuble = Produit::where('page',2)->get();
        return view('index',compact('indexmeuble'));
    }

}
```

//////******************The view code

```
@foreach( $indexcarrelage as $carre) 
        <div class="col-md-3 product-men">
            <div class="men-pro-item simpleCart_shelfItem">
                <div class="men-thumb-item">
                    <img  src="{{'images/'.$carre->image}}" alt="image" class="pro-image-front">
                    <img src="{{'images/'.$carre->image}}" alt="" class="pro-image-back">
                        <div class="men-cart-pro">
                            <div class="inner-men-cart-pro">
                                <a href="{{url('product_details',$carre->id)}}" class="link-product-add-cart">Afficher Produit</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="product-new-top">nouveaux</span>
                </div>
                <div class="item-info-product ">
                    <h4><a href="{{url('product_details',$carre->id)}}">{{$carre->nom}}</a></h4>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

// an other foreach to see the next product

```
@foreach( $indexcuisineas $cuis) 
            <div class="col-md-3 product-men">
                <div class="men-pro-item simpleCart_shelfItem">
                    <div class="men-thumb-item">
                        <img  src="{{'images/'.$cuis->image}}" alt="image" class="pro-image-front">
                        <img src="{{'images/'.$cuis->image}}" alt="" class="pro-image-back">
                            <div class="men-cart-pro">
                                <div class="inner-men-cart-pro">
                                    <a href="{{url('product_details',$cuis->id)}}" class="link-product-add-cart">Afficher Produit</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="product-new-top">nouveaux</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-info-product ">
                        <h4><a href="{{url('product_details',$cuis->id)}}">{{$carre->nom}}</a></h4>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

and keep on with the others product 
but this didn't work for me and i am new with laravel

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code, instead of posting a screenshot of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index()
{
    $indexcarrelage = Produit::where('page',13)->get();

    $indexcuisine = Produit::where('page',9)->get();

    $indexsalle = Produit::where('page',1)->get();

    $indexmeuble = Produit::where('page',2)->get();

    return view('index', compact(
        'indexcarrelage', 'indexcuisine', 'indexsalle', 'indexmeuble'
    ));
}
```

That would pass all those vars to your view.

Comment: this didn't work it show me the indexcarrelage  product but i can't see the indexcuisine  product